# How can I determine this element's selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've identified the element I want in Google Chrome, using inspect element.  What would be the er, path or syntax I would use to utilize a method for this element?  The tree(?) for the element is below:

```
html   body   div#contentDiv   div#searchFormDiv   div.searchFormFieldsLeft   form#companysearch.companySearchForm   fieldset   input#company
```

Answer (score 1):

The element you need has an ID, so use it:

```
var element = document.getElementById('company');
```